# How can I change the resolution of Iriun 4K Webcam?

Tags: usb, camera, usb-connection-mode, webcam

I use [Iriun 4K Webcam for PC and Mac](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jacksoftw.webcam) to use your Android phone's camera as a wireless or USB webcam in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. It is supposed to support resolutions up to 4K. (Max resolution depends on the phone).

I use a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10. However on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate it says that the resolution of Iriun is 640x480:

[image]

I don't see any option on the phone:

[image]

and https://iriun.com/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200920212032/http://web.archive.org/screenshot/https://iriun.com/)) seems to have no documentation.

How can I change the resolution of Iriun 4K Webcam?

---

Skype doesn't allow me to change the webcam resolution (clicking on "webcam setting" doesn't do anything):

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1) this might be device-depending, there are several reports like this in the ratings; 2) your Windows screen says to "check the settings of your video application" – have you checked them?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, "2) your Windows screen says to "check the settings of your video application" – have you checked them?" -> I thought this referred to the options on the phone that I took a screenshot of. I am not aware of the other options.

Comment: OK, just thought there might be more (e.g. in the app you want to use the cam with, like Skype or whatever). Sorry, I'm neither using the app nor Windows, so my "guess-limit" has been reached at this point. Good luck, hopefully there will be some solution! If you have the chance, maybe test with a different Android device and computer, to narrow down things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading Iriun 4K Webcam from 2.5.7 to [2.5.8](https://archive.org/details/iriun-4k-webcam) on Windows fixed the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

had the same problems with you by the version of 2.5.7 but I figured out the version of 2.5.4 has worked to change its resolution. maybe upgrade problems?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to change the resolution in whatever program you're using the webcam with and Iriun will sync with that resolution. For example I use OBS and in OBS you can change the res in Sources>Video Capture Device. If you're using Skype, Discord or whatever, you're gonna have to change the res in the settings. Once you do that the Iriun window will also change it's resolution to whatever you selected. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Skype doesn't allow me to change the webcam resolution (clicking on "webcam setting" doesn't do anything). https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyMHb.png